# How to modify vertex data when calling the mapTriplets method in Graphx of Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

The mapTriplets operation in Graphx of Spark can transform the triplets into some other form as the definition describes:

```
def mapTriplets[ED2](map: EdgeTriplet[VD, ED] => ED2): Graph[VD, ED2]
```

My data is a sparse bipartite graph, and the vertices data of an edge will be updated during each iteration. For example, here is an edge `(srcAttr, dstAttr, attr)`, the vertex of `srcAttr` and `dstAttr` will be modified according to `attr`. Therefore, what I need is to get all `(srcAttr, dstAttr, attr)` combinations, and use `attr` to update the `vertices`.

Graphx provides the `mapTriplets` method which can transform all (srcAttr, dstAttr, attr) combinations, but I cannot figure out how to modify vertex when executing this method.

So, is there any strategy that can modify the vertices when traversing all edges?

Answer (score 5):

> I cannot figure out how to modify vertex when executing this method

Because it is simply not possible. First of all GraphX data structures, same as other distributed data structures in Spark, are immutable. Moreover `mapTriplets` is designed to transforms edges not vertices.

> is there any strategy that can modify the vertices when traversing all edges?

If you want to transform vertices using edge data then `aggregateMessages` should give you what you want. It takes two functions

- one from `EdgeContext` to `Unit`, which can be used to send messages to the source and/or destination nodes
- second one which reduces messages for each vertex

and returns a `VertexRDD` which can be further used to construct a new graph.